# Passing value from a map function to a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I'm a little unsure how to take the value `showBtn` and pass it into my <`ListComponent />`

Here's the code:

```
  const listOptions = list.actionCollection
    .map((option) => {
      const showBtn = option.has(RENDER_BTN);

      // tried to assign showBtn to a value that could be passed to component below

      return option;
    });
```

```
{listOptions.map((option) => (
   <ListComponent option={option} key={option.key} />
))}
```

My check for `showBtn` is working fine (returning true or false) but I can't access `showBtn` outside of the map function. Obviously the map is checking through various values so some will be true & others false, so keeping the map syntax is important. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: `option.showBtn = showBtn;` is all you need. Of course you can also skip all that and use `{list.actionCollection.map((option) =>(<ListComponent someProp={option.has(RENDER_BTN)} ))}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an array of booleans, indicating on which index your condition is `true/false`:

```
 const listOptions = list.actionCollection
    .map((option) => ( //Implicit return
      const showBtn = option.has(RENDER_BTN);
    ));
```

`listOptions` will look something like: `[true, false, false, true...]`

And you can use this in your jsx:

```
{list.actionCollection.map((option, index) => (
   listOptions[index] && <ListComponent option={option} key={option.key} />
))}
```

Or, simply:

```
{list.actionCollection.map((option, index) => (
   option.has('RENDER_BTN') && <ListComponent option={option} key={option.key} />
))}
```

Comment: I think I get the idea, but then I'm just passing in booleans & not a showBtn value to my ListComponent that can be consumed in that component?

Comment: Notice I don't loop through `listOptions` but I use them as a condition.